# How to make slim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider guarantee sequence of the images it reads

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

I used following code to get a image from a dataset, but every time it returns different image.
Is it possible to guarantee the sequence of images got by DatasetDataProvider?

```py
provider = slim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider(dataset, num_readers=1, shuffle=False)
[image, label] = provider.get(["image", "label"])

images, labels = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=1, num_threads=1, capacity=1, enqueue_many=False)

batch_queue = slim.prefetch_queue.prefetch_queue([images, labels], capacity=1)

images, lables = batch_queue.dequeue()

sess = tf.Session()

data, label = sess.run([images, labels])
```